# pageviews counter updating with false data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this post table set up that has a `hits` column in it. The `hits` column is to store the number of times the post is viewed. The problem however is in the update query. The database is on my local(development) machine so I am the only user accessing the script. When I view a post, it updates but with fake data like if the current count there is 10 when I view the page it jumps to like 25 or so....pretty random....but incremental. I am wondering where I am going wrong. here is a code sample:

```
Public function getPost()
{
//some data query to get post data and the post id 
 $this->viewsCounter($pid);
Return post data as array.
}
```

The first method is okay now here is the `viewsCounter()` method

```
Public function viewsCounter($pid)
{ 
    $this->query("update post set hits=hits+1 where id='$pid' "); 
}
```

My `hits` column is set up this way `hits int(255) NOT NULL` please help anything am missing here?

Comment: Maybe you're calling `viewsCounter()` method more than once during single request?

Comment: `$this-query` ? isn't that `$this->query`?

Comment: hits int(255) NOT NULL is wrong make it int(11) and unsigned

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk its a single request. If I were to call it more that once I don't think I would be called up to 35 times ina single request...this error can increment upto 35 times the expected

Comment: @AD7six I don't understand your comment. Re-requesting the post how?...is it something I can correct from my code

Comment: @AD7six I am clling the viewsCounter method in the model file while the getPost method in my controller file. The controller extracts thhe post data and sends it to the view. the viewsCounter is more of a void method. Could this be the problem. Plus I have checked access logs, nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: @AD7six did the stack trace and the method I called only once per perrequest....I have also noticed that the increment is in multiples of 34. So if current count is 36 one execution of the script make it 68. As for the framework question yes I am using one but itz an inhouse code. Based on code Igniter though

Comment: have you demonstrated to yourself that the counter is incremented by one when you call `viewsCounter` once? If it goes up by 34 _what_ is the query that's responsible. if it goes up by 1 - you still need to identify how you are calling it 34 times per "view" (unless you have other code modifying the field value - you are). Good luck ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @AD7six said, the counter was being called 34 time..the error was comming from somewhere else. I used absolute urls to load some js and css files. The variable holding this URL was a little broken and the resources weren't loading well thus the extra views....thanks for your help everybody.

This a code snippet that caused the error

```
$file_path='http://mysite.com/resources';
```

Then on my page I did this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<? echo $files_path ;?>/css/style.css' type='text/css' />
```

This turned into relative urls because the file_path variable was not called. The relative url was appended to my current url thus creating an extra hit on the server as it attempts to get the resource.

Once again thanks.

Comment: Some more details would make this a good answer. +1 anyway and glad you found the problem and realized the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
//int(255) NOT NULL change it as int(11) unsigned and validate the pid

//add validation
<?php 

function viewsCounter($pid)
{ 
    //validate here
    if(!empty($pid))
    {
        $this->query("update post set hits=hits+1 where id='$pid' ");

    }else{
        //your error message goes
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238062/whats-the-difference-in-int11-and-int11-unsigned and Make your data as small as possible http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-size.html

Comment: Yeah me too...how does the whole int 11 unsigned affect my query and expected results

Comment: I agree.. I was responding to the question of "why change to int 11 unsigned"

Comment: interestingly `int(255)` "works" even though it's limited to 32 bit numbers https://gist.github.com/AD7six/b38e28316bdedba98d1b . anyway - 1.