# Save int number with + - symbol?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to save a number (int) in the database that usually have this format: `+36` or `-12`.
 How you can see there is a `+` or `-` in front of the number. 
Usually for save a `int` number I chose the `int (11)` in the type, but which type now I need to set for this circumstance?

Comment: As long as the `INT` is `SIGNED` (do **NOT** use `UNSIGNED`) then it can easily contain negative numbers. Why do you want a `+` in front of positive numbers, though?

Comment: The `+` in front of a positive number is not a property of the data, it's formatting. Use a signed `INT` column to store the data, format the values as you prefer in the client code.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I'm not entirely positive or negative numbers, or rather express the points difference there is between one player and another. So if I chose `int (11)` can I save also the symbol plus or minus?

Comment: There isn't any need to save the plus, no? Without any symbol a number is assumed to be positive. Just remember to set the column type to signed INT. For the plus sign you add it on the client/server side, by simply checking the number returned from SQL is less than 0 or not. If not, append a plus to the beginning.

Comment: @axiac in the attribute I only have: `BINARY` `UNSIGNED` `UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` `on UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP` but there is no `SIGNED`

Comment: It is signed when it is not `UNSIGNED` :-)

Comment: The difference between signed and unsigned INT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238062/whats-the-difference-in-int11-and-int11-unsigned

Comment: `SIGNED` is the same as the `UNSIGNED` box NOT ticked. As long as you DO NOT select `UNSIGNED` your column can easily contain both negative and positive numbers. How you want the formatting is specified by you SELECT'ing it in the format you want.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know this. Thanks to everyone.